# how to align text to the top in unordered list?

Tags: html, css

quick html question:

how can I align the text in this unordered list to the top of the div?

```
<div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li style="vertical-align:top"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>



/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
     vertical-align:top;

}

ul#menu li#greeting {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    color: #fff;

}

ul#menu li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    color: #034af3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;

}
```

Comment: Move the `align` statement to the `div`, not the `li`

Answer (score 6):

Seems like it would be by default, but this should fix any styles that are getting in the way.

```css
ul#menu li {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uyhHh/

Comment: This example doesn't really show anything, as it is a default value. If you try to change the `vertical-align` to `middle`, it will change nothing.

Comment: Agreed. It's not clear what the problem in the original question was. I hope that this would reveal something about that.

Comment: sorry forgot to put in the css rules

Comment: Here it is updated with your styles. I'm still not clear what the problem is. http://jsfiddle.net/uyhHh/2/

Comment: I just updated your fiddle, I would like to display the Home and about link displayed vertically aligned in the centre and the Hond and Cat link stay where it is.

Comment: It seems to behave that way when display:inline-block is applied to the contents of li. Then the number goes to the bottom.